# How to slightly shorten a Rightarrow in tikzcd?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I want to draw a triangular 2-cell diagram in tikz. The obvious attempt is the following.

```
\[\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3em]
a  \arrow{dr} &
\\ b \arrow{u} \arrow[""{name=foo}]{r} & c
\arrow[Rightarrow, from=foo, to=1-1]  \end{tikzcd}\]
```

However, the Rightarrow comes far too close to the object `a` for my liking. I tried shortening it by adding `, shorten=2ex` but got an error. How can I shorten the Rightarrow but maintain its direction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key to shorten the `>` end of an arrow is `shorten >`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3em]
a  \arrow{dr} &
\\ b \arrow{u} \arrow[""{name=foo}]{r} & c
\arrow[Rightarrow, from=foo, to=1-1,shorten >=1.5ex]  
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd probably go for a more symmetric version, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3em]
&a  \arrow{dr} & \\ 
b \arrow{ur}  \arrow[""{name=foo}]{rr} && c
\arrow[Rightarrow, from=foo, to=1-2,shorten >=0.5ex]  
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The other end can be shortened with `shorten <`, and it might be useful to keep in mind that one can make arrows longer by shortening them by a negative distance, e.g. `shorten >=-1ex`.

Comment: I tried the very same thing but had a syntax error. Ah well. Thanks!